# GCC compiler error

Tags: c, unix, gcc, linker

```
main: main.o print.o credits.o hello.o
        gcc -o main main.o print.o credits.o hello.o

main.o: main.c hello.h
        gcc -c -o main.o main.c

print.o: print.c hello.h
        gcc -c -o print.o print.c

credits.o: credits.c hello.h
        gcc -c -o credits.o credits.c

hello.o: hello.h
        gcc -c -o hello.o hello.h
```

I get this error when I use the make command

```
/usr/bin/ld:hello.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:hello.o:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: Is there a `hello.c` ? You are trying to compile the `.h`...

Answer (score 4):

You should change the second last and last line -

`hello.o: hello.h` to `hello.o: hello.c hello.h`

`gcc -c -o hello.o hello.h` to `gcc -c -o hello.o hello.c`

The input here should be a c file.

For more understanding I would recommend you look at this [link](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Misc/Unix-info/make/make_2.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to compile a .h file,ie hello.h
It should be hello.c that you should be compiling

```
main: main.o print.o credits.o hello.o
    gcc -o main main.o print.o credits.o hello.o

main.o: main.c hello.h
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c

print.o: print.c hello.h
    gcc -c -o print.o print.c

credits.o: credits.c hello.h
    gcc -c -o credits.o credits.c

hello.o: hello.c hello.h
    gcc -c -o hello.o hello.c
```

Should Work